# C# - Adding objects that implement interfaces to a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

I have a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<Type, IExample> examples;
```

I have two classes that implement the interface:

```
public class Example1 : IExample
{
}

public class Example2 : IExample
{
}
```

I have created a way to get an instance from the dictionary if it exists but am trying to figure out a way to instantiate a new object if it doesn't exist.

```
public T GetExample<T>() where T : IExample
{
    // Return the signal if it exists
    if (examples.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        IExample value;

        if (!examples.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value))
        {
            // unable to get value
        }

        return (T)value;
    }

    // Stuck on this line here. How exactly do I instantiate a new example if it doesn't exist.
    examples.Add(typeof(T), new );

    return default(T);
}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Side note: I don't like "getter" methods that mutate the state. A `GetSomething()` method should only *get* the 'something', not add something to the dictionary. A better Name for your function would perhaps be `GetOrCreateExample<T>()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would need to add a generic type parameter constraint on your generic method for parameter-less constructor and then you can instantiate the type `T` parameter like `new T()`:

```
public T GetExample<T>() where T : IExample,class,new()
{
       IExample value;

       if (examples.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value))
       {
           return (T)value;
       }


   T obj =  new T(); // create instance of T and use further down in code it's reference
   examples.Add(typeof(T),obj );

   return obj ;
}
```

and `return default(T);` would return `null` not a new instance of `T` as for class (**Reference Types**) default value is `null`, i doubt you want to do `return new T();` there, which will create a new object and will return the reference to it back to caller.

Comment: The compiler is complaining about the double where statement. "A constraint clause has already been specified"

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I would remove `ContainsKey` as `TryGetValue` itself is sufficient not to raise exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Although you can certainly make a type constraint requiring a default constructor, it is often too constraining: users of your code may be reluctant to make a default constructor public, or have no default constructor at all.

A more flexible approach takes a delegate that creates a missing object:

```
public T GetExample<T>(Func<T> make) where T : IExample, class {
    IExample value;
    if (examples.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value)) {
        return (T)value;
    }
    T res =  make();
    examples.Add(typeof(T), res);
    return res;
}
```

This way the caller is in control of how to create new objects when the object that you need is not cached in the `examples`. Your code calls back "on demand", so the object creation logic remains firmly hidden in the caller's code, for example

```
var e = exampleFactory.GetExample<MyExample>(
    () => new MyExample(firstParameter, secondParameter)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to instantiate a generic type:

```
var newInstance =  return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

As Ehsan noted, you need to add a constraint to the type `T` so it can be instantiated: `where T: class`.

Or you add the `new()` constraint `where T: new()`. Then you can instantiate it as

```
var newInstance = new T();
```

Comment: Thank you. Trying to avoid reflection but I appreciate having the option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new constraint @EhsanSajjad suggested and create a generic extension method for the dictionary:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetOrCreate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) where TValue : new()
    {
        var exists = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value);

        if (!exists)
        {
            value = new TValue();

            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

`out var` will only work if you use **C# 7**, otherwise you have to split the line.

Or even better with an optional default value you can pass:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetOrCreate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = null) where TValue : class, new()
    {
        var exists = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value);

        if (!exists)
        {
            value = defaultValue ?? new TValue();

            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't add the newly instanced object to the dictionary, which it should.

Comment: When `exists` is true, `dictionary.Add()` throws because the key already exists.  Also, the new object is still not added to the dictionary.  Also, what if null is an expected default value?

Comment: @piedar and this is why you don't rush writing code... fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Ehsan's answer, here's how I would do it:

```
public T GetExample<T>() where T : IExample,class,new()
{

    IExample value;

    if (!examples.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value))
    {
        // Object doesn't exist. Create and add
        value = new T();
        examples.Add(typeof(T), value);
    }

    return (T)value;
}
```

Using both `ContainsKey` and `TryGetValue` is redundant.